# how to set tinymce default content

Tags: tinymce, default

My tinymce version is 3.5.8. I want to set the default content, and try the way on official website and other ways by google, but all error. Some of error as below:

```
TypeError: tinyMCE.activeEditor is null
[Break On This Error] 
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent('<strong>Some contents</strong>');



TypeError: tinyMCE.get(...) is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

tinyMCE.get('content').setContent('<strong>Some contents</strong>');
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just find a method to fix the default content. Just add both name and id to the textarea, then you can put the content between tag textarea, and the content will be show.

Answer (score 16):

This is likely because the tinyMCE editor has not been initialized yet. If you run your tinyMCE.init() function then right after in the script try to do a setContent call, it will fail because the init() function is still running.

What you can do is specify an [init_instance_callback](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#init_instance_callback), which will run after the tinyMCE editor is initialized. Running your setContent call in this callback will successfully set the content of the editor.

E.g.

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    init_instance_callback: "insert_contents",
});


function insert_contents(inst){
    inst.setContent('<strong>Some contents</strong>');  
}
```